# Extract mathmatical and greek superscripts in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, symbols

I need to build a list of superscripts in a document which is fine until I get to symbols for things like partial derivatives which instead return as ? in my array instead of ∂. What could I add to capture the actual symbol? Thanks

```vb
    Dim i As Long, j As String
    Dim txtboxString() As String
    Dim Superscript As String
    Dim myrange As range
    Dim ap As Document: Set ap = ActiveDocument
    
    x = 0
    
    For i = 1 To ap.Characters.Count
        j = ""
        If ActiveDocument.Characters(i).Font.Superscript = True Then
            Z = 0
            ReDim Preserve txtboxString(x + 1)
            For Z = i To i - 5 Step -1
            If Z > ap.Characters.Count Then GoTo 1
            If ActiveDocument.Characters(Z) = "," Then GoTo 0
            If ActiveDocument.Characters(Z).Font.Superscript = True Then j = ActiveDocument.Characters(Z) & j
            Next Z
        End If

0: If j <> "" Then
        If j <> "," Then
            If j <> "?" Then
        
        txtboxString(x) = j
        x = x + 1
    End If
    End If
    End If
    If Z + 1 > ap.Characters.Count Then i = Z 'Else i = Z + 1
    Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Characters(i + 1)
    myrange.MoveUntil Cset:="* "
    i = myrange.End - 1
    Next
```

Comment: Maybe your textbox can't display those characters?  Have you tried writing them to a document?

Comment: Thank you I did not know that the array variable and printed variable could be "different"